# Having a problem with simple bool

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've some really simple code that checks if my bool is == YES but it does not ever enter.

```
NSLog(@"boool %d",self.arrayAlreadyPopulated );

if (self.arrayAlreadyPopulated == YES) 
{
Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchScoresArray objectAtIndex:(numMatchCounter)];
aMatch.teamName1 = TeamNameHolder;
}
else 
{

Match *aMatch = [[Match alloc] init];
aMatch.teamName1 = TeamNameHolder;
    [appDelegate.matchScoresArray addObject:aMatch];
[aMatch release];
}
```

The debug at the top says that the value of self.arrayAlreadyPopulated is 1 on the 2nd pass as it should be.

But it never enters the first first part but jumps down to the 'else'

I cant see for the life of me what the problem is. -.-

Anybody able to clue me in?

Thanks
-Code

EDIT declaration code

```
BOOL arrayAlreadyPopulated;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL arrayAlreadyPopulated;

@synthesize arrayAlreadyPopulated;
```

Comment: How is `arrayAlreadyPopulated` declared?  Can you paste the code?

Comment: @Mike added in the code as you requested.

Comment: Why an int? A BOOL should work fine with `(assign)`.

Comment: How do you know it does never visit the first part? My guess is that aMatch is nil because the data isn't set up properly at this point. Also, TeamNameHolder probably violates naming conventions - not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare a `BOOL` against `YES` or `NO`. They can carry values that are not `NO` but don't compare equal to `YES`. Instead, use the boolean expression directly in the `if` statement:

```
if (self.arrayAlreadyPopulated)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What's happening behind the scenes with your example? Do you mean that the conditional check there is effectively `if (self. arrayAlreadyPopulated != NO)`?

Comment: No, I mean `self.arrayAlreadyPopulated != NO` is converted by the compiler into a boolean value (an `int` of value `1` or `0`) and then that is checked. In other words, it's redundant. ;)

Comment: Ah, the redundant part I get. I thought you were saying the result would be different.

Comment: The check I posted will be different from the check you posted in your original question. `YES` is defined as `1`. What if your `BOOL` is `2`?

Comment: It's not my question, I'm just curious about your answer. I only use `if (myBool)` and `if (!myBool)` so it's not an issue. I guess I just haven't written code that would allow my BOOLs to ever become anything but 1 and 0, using `NSNumber`s with `boolValue` and `numberWithBool` to ensure appropriate values whenever there might be doubt. Still, I can see your point if you're not conscientious about it, setting your BOOLs to unknown value ints and such.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayAlreadyPopulated` is probably not actually a BOOL. If, for example, it was a float, the %d would still print 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check and double check that you're assigning the value to `arrayAlreadyPopulated` always as `self.arrayAlreadyPopulated = YES` instead of just `arrayAlreadyPopulated = YES`.

Sometimes, using the property v/s the associated variable of the property *interchangeably* doesn't always work out the way you'd expect it to. Use the "variable" name **only** if you're using it to release memory by `[variable release]` statement, just the way you'll find it in any Apple example code. In all other cases use `self.propertyname`.